# dplyr, data.table and setDT interaction issue

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

This is a very simplified version of a problem in a much bigger scale.
The objective is to use `data.table` structure and `dplyr` commands for faster ordering and grouping on multiple columns.

The correct version is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(lubridate)

# data set
dt = data.frame(id = c("a","b", "a"),
                date = ymd(c("2016-01-03","2016-01-02","2016-01-01")),
                value = c(10,5,9), stringsAsFactors = F)

# process to get the id of the largest value
(setDT(dt, key=c("id","value")) %>% select(id,value) %>% arrange(desc(value)) %>% slice(1))$id -> picked_id

# return all rows of this id
dt %>% filter(id %in% picked_id)

# id          date value
# 1:  a 2016-01-01     9
# 2:  a 2016-01-03    10
```

But when I try to use `setDT` in a different position in my script I get a different result:

```
dt = data.frame(id = c("a","b", "a"),
                date = ymd(c("2016-01-03","2016-01-02","2016-01-01")),
                value = c(10,5,9), stringsAsFactors = F)

(dt %>% select(id,value) %>% setDT(., key=c("id","value")) %>% arrange(desc(value)) %>% slice(1))$id -> picked_id

dt %>% filter(id %in% picked_id)

#   id       date value
# 1  a 2016-01-03     9
# 2  a 2016-01-02    10
```

Obviously, there are other much more understandable scripts for this simple task, but I want to understand why this issue occurs here.

Comment: The two `dt` variables don't define the same data frame. If I use one, I get consistent results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot safely mix (i) data.table's functions that modify by reference into (ii) a dplyr chain, which is designed to never modify by reference. See what happens here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(lubridate)

dt = data.frame(id = c("a","b", "a"),
                date = ymd(c("2016-01-03","2016-01-02","2016-01-01")),
                value = c(10,5,9), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt


  id       date value
1  a 2016-01-03    10
2  b 2016-01-02     5
3  a 2016-01-01     9


dt %>% select(id,value) %>% setDT(., key=c("id","value"))

dt


  id       date value
1  a 2016-01-03     9
2  a 2016-01-02    10
3  b 2016-01-01     5
```

So the `select`ed columns have been modified by `setDT` call. You could view this as a bug in dtplyr's implementation of `select` or as a misuse by the OP. Anyways, I would stick with one paradigm at a time (personally, I just use data.table with magrittr and never hit these problems). For now, you can add a `copy` to your chain,

```
dt %>% select(id,value) %>% copy %>% setDT(., key=c("id","value"))
```

But I guess you'd need to do this all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's my mistake basically. I had the wrong impression that dtplyr package would be able to solve those issues.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your answer (yet). Your example of a chain doesn't save/print the result, it updates `select()` output in place but does not assign to new variable, it should because `select()` results aren't saved into any variable. Not sure about `copy` too, see: `dt %>% select(id,value) %>% setDT(., key=c("id","value")) -> ans1; dt %>% select(id,value) %>% copy %>% setDT(., key=c("id","value")) -> ans2; all.equal(ans1, ans2)`.

Comment: @jangorecki I don't think your example works. The first one already modifies `dt` in place, so the second one doesn't have a chance to work with the original `dt`. My suggestion doesn't save the result with `<-`, `->` or `=`, but I guess the OP can figure how to do that, or did you mean something else?

Comment: @AntoniosK Maybe it is meant to solve these issues. You could ask on the dtplyr issue tracker to clarify. I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Frank no it doesn't, I see have `class(dt) # [1] "data.frame"` after running those commands. `setDT` updates in place, but not `dt`, just the `select()` output that isn't stored anywhere.

Comment: @jangorecki Ok, I see what you're saying. Let's continue in chat. I'm going to post what I'm looking at there.